# sql query in ms access with exists too slow

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT sb,
       suchbegriff_artnr,
       suchbegriff_lfdnrkal
FROM
  (SELECT kvks.artnr & '/' & kvks.[lfdnr-kal] AS sb,
          VAL(LEFT(kvks.suchbegriff, 6)) AS suchbegriff_artnr,
          VAL(RIGHT(kvks.suchbegriff, 4)) AS suchbegriff_lfdnrkal
   FROM kvks
   WHERE kvks.suchbegriff LIKE '*/*')
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM stammdat
     WHERE stammdat.artnr=suchbegriff_artnr
       AND stammdat.[lfdnr-kal]=suchbegriff_lfdnrkal)
```

It executes, but it is too slow. It takes arount 5 secs.
The `kvks` table contains about 70k records, the `stammdat` table about 4,5k.
Whit this query, I would like to have the records from the `kvks` table, which isn't in the `stammdat` table based on two conditions.

The `stammdat.artnr` and `stammdat.[lfdnr-kal]` are integers.

How could I speed up this query?

**EDIT**

I wrote a query, with wich I store the one half of the query:

```
INSERT INTO teszt
SELECT kvks.artnr AS sb_artnr,
       kvks.[lfdnr-kal] AS sb_lfdnrkal,
       LEFT(kvks.suchbegriff,6) AS suchbegriff_artnr,
       RIGHT(kvks.suchbegriff,4) AS suchbegriff_lfdnrkal
FROM kvks
WHERE kvks.suchbegriff LIKE '*/*'
```

And then I don't need this functions:

```
SELECT teszt.sb_artnr,
       teszt.sb_lfdnrkal,
       teszt.suchbegriff_artnr,
       teszt.suchbegriff_lfdnrkal
FROM teszt
WHERE NOT exists
    (SELECT 1
     FROM stammdat
     WHERE stammdat.artnr=teszt.suchbegriff_artnr
       AND stammdat.[lfdnr-kal]=teszt.suchbegriff_lfdnrkal)
```

But the speed is slow still now.

**EDIT2**

I have it:

```
SELECT teszt.sb_artnr,
       teszt.sb_lfdnrkal,
       teszt.suchbegriff_artnr,
       teszt.suchbegriff_lfdnrkal
FROM teszt
LEFT JOIN stammdat ON stammdat.artnr=teszt.suchbegriff_artnr
AND stammdat.[lfdnr-kal]=teszt.suchbegriff_lfdnrkal
WHERE stammdat.artnr IS NULL
```

Comment: You could try a left join instead of NOT EXISTS, but it probably won't do much good. The problem is that all of your criteria is based on functions. That means every single row must be processed/evaluated, so no indexes can be used. If you break out the data that will be used for where & join clause criteria, into separate fields and index them, you will see a significant improvement.

Comment: "If you break out the data that will be used for where & join clause criteria, into separate fields" - Can I do it with modifying the sql query? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the WHERE clause is the culprit. It's a pattern match against all the tuples. Start by taking that out completely and re-timing just the first query that creates teszt. If it's significantly faster then you will need a different strategy.